# MAMP- Local Server shows only a blank page instead of the site pages

Tags: php, mamp

I am on Mac OSX 10.6.5 & have MAMP installed on my machine. I have had a website developed by a third party that I am now trying to set up on my local server. The developer has given me the SiteSettings.php to use here. However When I start the local server, all I see is a blank page. Any help setting this up is highly appreciated.

Here is my SiteConfig.php:

```
<?php
 #$application = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $application = "local";

 if ($application == "local"){
   define("HST","localhost");
   define("USR","root");
   define("PWD","root");
   define("DBN","fs");
   define("DBTYPE","mysql");
   #define("SITEROOT",      "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/fs");
   define("SITEROOT",       "http://localhost:8888/fs/test");
   #define("ABSPATH",       "/opt/lampp/htdocs/fs");
   define("ABSPATH",        "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fs/test");

   define("SMT_TEMPLATES",  ABSPATH."/templates");
   define("SMT_TEMPLATES_C",    ABSPATH."/templates_c");
   define("SMT_CONFIG",     ABSPATH."/configs");
     }

    #the following is for connection to the web server
    else{
   define("HST",            "");
   define("USR",            "");
   define("PWD",            "");
   define("DBN",            "");
   define("DBTYPE",     "");
   define("SITEROOT",       "");
   define("SITEROOT1",      "");
   define("ABSPATH",        "");

   define("SMT_TEMPLATES",   ABSPATH."/templates");
   define("SMT_TEMPLATES_C",    ABSPATH."/templates_c");
   define("SMT_CONFIG",     ABSPATH."/configs");
   //echo ABSPATH;exit;
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try dropping to a shell and tail the error logs;

```
tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log
```

and/or

```
tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have only provided the configuration file. There is nothing being output here. just definitions. Try adding `echo "hi"`to the bottom of the page, before the `?>` and let me know what happens when you go to the `siteconfig.php` site again